# Quelles sont les différences entre "silent" et "silencieux", s'il y en a?

Tags: vocabulaire, langage-informel

Je travaille en Belgique, en Wallonie, tout près de la France.

Régulièrement, j'entends mes collègues utiliser le mot "silent".
Je ne retrouve pas ce mot dans [la version "en-ligne" de Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr).

Est-ce un anglicisme ? Est-ce correct, fautif, ... ?

Comment: Tu es sûr que c'est « silent » et pas « silence » ?

Comment: @None: Oui, j'en suis certain.

Comment: "Silent" prononcé *saïlent'* à l'anglaise ou *silen* à la française ?

Comment: @XouDo: c'est prononcé *silen* à la française et ça signifie "silencieux".

Comment: homophonie: si lent, pas rapide. Il vaut mieux nous donner une phrase, quand même.

Comment: Qui sait, _s'il en_ est ?

Comment: Est-ce employé comme adjectif ou substantif ? Dans quel contexte ? Le *T* final est-il prononcé ? Qui sont ces collègues ? Pourquoi ne pas leur avoir demandé d'explications ?

Comment: [*Silent*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dmf/silent) est un mot du Moyen Français et tout à fait inusité depuis des lustres dans l'hexagone. En dehors de tout contexte donné dans la question toute réponse ne peut être que spéculation. Es-tu sûr qu'il s'agit d'un mot français et non pas d'un mot issu d'un dialecte Wallon vernaculaire qui subsisterait dans la langue de tous les jours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cet adjectif est bien attesté dans la langue française, il signifie bien « silencieux », mais il est rarement utilisé ; le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/silencieux) fournit cette information.

> **Silent, -ente**, adj., littér., rare. Silencieux.
> ♦ Je ne sais plus si j'en préfère le marais silent, ou si l'ardente fièvre m'en séduit davantage.(Suarès,Voy. Condottière, t. 1, 1910, p. 271)

Comment: Rarement est un euphémisme.

Comment: @jlliagre Si jamais quelque organisation se met un jour en tête de continuer ce travail soigneux de présentation de la langue française qu'est le TLFi, et de le maintenir, alors peut-être qu'une révision changera « rare » en « très rare ».

Comment: Le TLFi n'a pas vocation a être révisé. C'est un peu comme le Littré. Il faut le prendre pour ce qu'il est. Quand la seule citation date de 1910, il faut se poser des questions...

Comment: [***Avertissement** : la rédaction du TLF est terminée depuis 1994 et la plupart des contributeurs ont quitté le laboratoire. Il n’a pas vocation à être mis à jour. Cette ressource, qui ne fait pas l’objet d’une veille lexicographique, est donc close « en l’état ». Il est donc tout à fait naturel que les définitions qui s’y trouvent ne rendent pas compte des évolutions de la société.*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/)

Comment: De plus, le TLFi dit *littéraire* qui, indépendamment de la rareté, implique que le mot a peu de chance de se retrouver à l'oral, prononcé par des "collègues". Il reste cependant la possibilité d'un wallonisme, à investiguer.

Comment: @jlliagre  Peu importe ce que pensent les  auteurs, c'est l  seule travail lexicographique  sérieux qui considère la langue dans beaucoup de détail, dont les méthodes sont un modèle qui mérite d'être retenu, et qui peut être amélioré. Il n'est nullement interdit de reprendre le format _et_ le contenu et d'améliorer tout ça, notamment en ajoutant un traitement de la langue non littéraire, avec des examples (ce qui manque le plus). Ce n'est qu'une question de volonté.

Comment: @jlliagre Littéraire… si on veux:  **piger** 1. Arg. et pop. Synon. piquer

Comment: Qu'est ce que ***piger*** vient faire là dedans ?

Comment: Ce n'est qu'une question de volonté... et de moyens aussi: *la construction d’un dictionnaire de langue tel le Trésor de la Langue française a nécessité près de cent personnes durant trente ans*.

Comment: @jlliagre Ce n'est qu'un exemple de tout le vocabulaire populaire et argotique que l'on trouve dans ce dictionnaire, pour dire qu'il n'est pas exactement « littéraire ».// « a nécessité près de cent personnes durant trente ans » : Ah ? Alors passons nous d'un meilleur dictionnaire…

Comment: Je n'ai jamais écrit que le TLFi ne contenait que des mots littéraires.

Comment: Est-ce un belgicisme, car je n'ai jamais lu ni entendu ce mot en France?

Comment: @XouDo Je n'en sais rien.  Il me semble qu'on n'a jamais employé de belgicismes en français. Comme Suarès était un poète et critique français, et qu'apparemment il n'avait pas de connexion particulière avec la Belgique, il y a de forte chances que ce mot provienne de la culture française (possiblement après emprunt à l'anglais). En plus le dictionnaire n'inclut aucune mention particulière (sauf « rare »)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Suar%C3%A8s //  Moi non plus, je ne le connaissais pas (pas une référence en la matière , je n'ai pas une connaissance  très étendue du français).

Comment: @LPH oui comprends bien, c'est juste que cela semble un mot très rare et plutôt littéraire, pas vraiment le genre qu'on imagine utilisé autour de la machine à café le matin à 10h (à moins peut-être de travailler chez un éditeur).

Comment: *Silent* c'est aussi la 3e personne du pluriel du verbe *siler* qui est inconnu en français de France mais est employé au Québec (siffler dans l'hexagone). Et en Breton il existe *silañ* qui veut dire filtrer.

Comment: @LPH *Il ne me semble qu'on n'a jamais employé de belgicismes en français* ? Tu veux peut-être dire *en France* car sinon, les belgicismes ne se rencontrent guère qu'en français...

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, bien sûr, c'est ce que je voulais dire, le français tel qu'il est parlé en France ; je n'ai pas l'impression qu'il y en ait beaucoup. Par exemple, il ne m'a jamais semblé que Brel  et Halliday utilisait un français qui diffère en quelque manière, sauf légèrement pour la prononciation chez Brel.

Comment: @LPH je serais quand-même fort surpris que Brel utilise soixante-dix, quatre-vingt-dix, endive. De plus Johnny Hallyday n'a jamais été belge...

Comment: @LaurentS. J'ai vérifié et en effet il n'avait qu'une forte connection avec la Belgique: son père était Belge, mais lui est né à Paris et y a grandi.

Comment: @LPH Johnny Halliday n'a jamais vécu en Belgique et a rencontré son père pour la première fois à 21 ans, très brièvement. Il l'a très peu vu ensuite. Pas idéal pour une transmission de belgicismes...

Comment: @LaurentS. Exact: *Les Flamandes ça n'est pas souriant / Si elles dansent c'est qu'elles ont septante ans / Qu'à septante ans il est bon de montrer / Que tout va bien que poussent les petits-enfants*